# Outlook Add-In disabled because too slow

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, add-in

I am developing a simple Add-In for Outlook with C#. Now as I was testing the release, suddenly Outlook print an error message and disables my Add-In:

`This add-in caused Outlook to start slowly. (1.594 seconds)`

I am not sure what causes this. All I do `Onload` are these this:

**Ribbon Button**
I am using a single ribbon button which I initialize in my AddIn as follows:

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
      return new MyRibbonButton();
    }
```

**Ribbon Button constructor**
The ribbon button initialize an object. So nothing special yet.

```
public MyRibbonButton()
{
    this.guiSettings = new AppSettingsManager(root.localmachine, "GUI", false);
}

...

public AppSettingsManager(root type, string subpath, bool writable)
{
    if (subpath != "")
    {
        this.PATH += @"\" + subpath;
    }
    this.type = type;
    this.writable = writable;
}
```

**Icon**
In the same `MyRibbonButton` class I declare the icon I want to use for my button depending on a value in the registry.

```
public Bitmap imageSuper_GetNotifyImage(IRibbonControl control)
{
    switch (guiSettings.GetValueInt32("Icon", 1))
    {
        case 1:
            return Properties.Resources.icon1;
        case 2:
            return Properties.Resources.icon2;
        case 3:
            return Properties.Resources.icon3;
        default:
            return Properties.Resources.icon1;
    }

}
```

As you can see I don't do anyting special except maybe the Registry Read in the last part. Do you think this causes Outlook to start slowly? If so, how can I optimize it.

Comment: I have a plugin which is almost as simple as yours, I too get the same problem.  Mine just adds listeners to 3 events.. i gave up and reverted to macros

Comment: @BugFinder Please let me know, if you find something out. Do you know how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I concluded that something in the whole .net framework provided already makes it "slow" according to outlook.. As I was doing it to make my life easier and it was proving to be anything but, I abandoned the idea.

Comment: @BugFinder Sad to hear. Unfortunately I have to stick to Add-Ins. Seems like I have to find a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You get penalized for loading the .Net system. There used to be a "warmup" registry key which could be used to force Outlook to load the right version of the .Net run-time without being penalized, but that key no longer works.

The only way I was able to work around that problem is to create a stub addin in Delphi (C++ would work just as well if not better) that did nothing but get loaded by Outlook (in about 20ms)  and start a timer. When the timer fires (Outlook would be idle and not monitoring the addin), it would load the slave .Net addin using the [IManagedAddin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/imanagedaddin-interface?view=vs-2017) interface.

Comment: is that something you have blogged/shared, or would be willing to share? Sounds like it would be massively helpful

Comment: Nothing I can share - it is a part of a commercial product. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks. Always appreciate your knowledge sharing here!